# Conflicts in JS

Tags: javascript, header, slider, swiper.js

I'm having a problem.When there is a slider with its DOM on the site page (`data-swiper-card="cars"`), the header menu does not open, I click on the burger and it does not open, it also has its own call (`data-menu-toggle="menu"`)

**Script and call slider:**

```
    `<div class="card-slider swiper description__slider" data-swiper-card="cars">`

    `function (e, t, n) {
        "use strict";
        n.r(t), n.d(t, "initCardSlider", (function () {
            return i
        }));
        var i = function () {
            var e = document.querySelector(".card__slider-wrapper") || document.querySelector("[data-       slider-wrapper]"),
                t = new window.Swiper("[data-swiper-card]", {
                    loop: !0,
                    loopFillGroupWithBlank: !0,
                    spaceBetween: 24,
                    effect: "fade",
                    navigation: {
                        nextEl: "[data-swiper-card] .group-buttons__next",
                        prevEl: "[data-swiper-card] .group-buttons__back"
                    },
                    a11y: {prevSlideMessage: "Предыдущий слайд", nextSlideMessage: "Следующий слайд"}
                });
            t.on("slideChangeTransitionStart", (function () {
            })), t.on("slideNextTransitionStart", (function () {
                e.classList.remove("back"), e.classList.add("next")
            })), t.on("slidePrevTransitionStart", (function () {
                e.querySelector(".swiper-slide-next").style.opacity = 1, setTimeout((function () {
                    e.querySelector(".swiper-slide-next").style.opacity = 0
                }), 500), e.classList.remove("next"), e.classList.add("back")
            })), t.on("slidePrevTransitionEnd", (function () {
            }))
        }
    }, "./js/modules/sliders/init-swiper-advantages.js":`

Script and call header:
/*! exports provided: initMenu */function (e, t, n) {
        "use strict";
        n.r(t), n.d(t, "initMenu", (function () {
            return o
        }));
        var i = n(/*! ./init-accordion */"./js/modules/init-accordion.js"), o = function () {
            var e = document.querySelector("header"), t = document.querySelector('[data-menu-toggle="menu"]'),
                n = document.querySelector('[data-menu-toggle="phone"]'),
                o = document.querySelector('[data-menu="contacts"]'),
                a = document.querySelector('[data-menu="overlay"]'), r = document.querySelector(".header__wrapper"),
                s = document.querySelector(".header__bottom-wrapper"), c = document.querySelector(".main-nav");
            if (e && t && n) {
                a && a.addEventListener("click", (function () {
                    e.classList.remove("is-contacts-open"), a.classList.remove("is-show"), window.enableBodyScroll(s)
                })), t.addEventListener("click", (function (t) {
                    e.classList.contains("is-menu-open") ? (window.enableBodyScroll(s), e.classList.remove("is-open-end"), c && i.accordions.closeAllAccordion(c)) : (window.disableBodyScroll(s, {
                        reserveScrollBarGap: !0,
                        allowTouchMove: function (e) {
                            for (; e && e !== document.body;) {
                                if (null !== e.getAttribute("body-scroll-lock-ignore")) return !0;
                                e = e.parentElement
                            }
                        }
                    }), setTimeout((function () {
                        e.classList.add("is-open-end")
                    }), 1e3)), e.classList.toggle("is-menu-open"), e.classList.remove("is-contacts-open"), a.classList.remove("is-show"), t.currentTarget.blur()
                })), n.addEventListener("click", (function (t) {
                    o && (e.classList.contains("is-contacts-open") ? (window.enableBodyScroll(e), e.classList.add("animating-contact"), r && r.addEventListener("transitionend", (function () {
                        e.classList.remove("animating-contact")
                    }))) : window.disableBodyScroll(e, {reserveScrollBarGap: !0}), e.classList.toggle("is-contacts-open"), a && a.classList.toggle("is-show"), t.currentTarget.blur())
                })), window.addEventListener("resize", (function () {
                    e.classList.contains("is-menu-open") && window.disableBodyScroll(s, {
                        reserveScrollBarGap: !0,
                        allowTouchMove: function (e) {
                            for (; e && e !== document.body;) {
                                if (null !== e.getAttribute("body-scroll-lock-ignore")) return !0;
                                e = e.parentElement
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }))
            }
        }
    }, "./js/modules/init-modal-animation.js":
```

I tried to reassign, an error still occurs, I also wrote a handler that should not block the opening of the header.

Comment: Hi Vladislav and welcome to SO. Please take the time to refactor your question and properly format the code. Be sure to include the relevant code for any part of your application that you mention. Also it looks like your code is somehow minified, which makes it very hard to read and understand. If possible provide the code before it has been bundled, transpiled and minified. Doing all this will make it easier for us to help you.